# Investing after marriage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cannot seem to invest in ghorza gra-bagol after I marry her. I have both the required skill tree park and gold to do so, but it only gives me the option to say that I'll do it later.

Comment: What mods do you have?